# Using result for closed intervals, prove every interval is equal to its length: using only epsilon?

Tags: real-analysis

Given that for every closed interval $J=[a,b]$, $m^*(J) = |J| = b-a$, prove that for **any** interval $I$, $m^*(I) = |I|$.

My understanding of the correct proof is as follows:

First, prove $m^*(I)\leq |I|$ where $I$ is any interval of length $b-a$. Take its closure, $I'=[a,b]$.
By monotonicity, $I \subset I' \Rightarrow m^*(I) \leq m^*(I') = |I|$.

Now, prove $m^*(I) \geq |I|$.  For all $\epsilon>0$ consider a closed interval $I'=[a+\epsilon/2, b-\epsilon/2]$,
noting that $I'\subset I$.  By monotonicity, $m^*(I) \geq m^*(I') = b-a - \epsilon$. Taking $\epsilon$ to be arbitrarily small, we have $m^*(I) \geq |I|$, giving us $m^*(I) = |I|$

---

I am trying to understand in what situations I can use these "$\epsilon >0$ arguments," which are extremely common in Real Analysis.  **Why could I not prove both directions using an "$\epsilon >0$ argument?"**  For example, instead of taking the closure, to just use a slightly large interval:

Prove $m^*(I)\leq |I|$ where $I$ is any interval of length $b-a$. For all $\epsilon>0$ consider a closed interval $I'=[a-\epsilon/2, b+\epsilon/2]$,
noting that $I\subset I'$.  By monotonicity, $m^*(I) \leq m^*(I') = b-a + \epsilon$. Taking $\epsilon$ to be arbitrarily small, we have $m^*(I) \leq |I|$, giving us $m^*(I) = |I|$

I would greatly appreciate if you could help me understand why I cannot use $\epsilon$ arguments in both cases--or if I am totally wrong about even the "correct" proof, to please provide some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Because then you're just proving that any larger closed interval has the norm, which was assumed.

The point of the proof is to show that the norm associated with an interval is not impacted if it is missing limit points.

$m*(a,b)=m*[a,b] $

You're using the assumption to do that

I mean if you wanted to, you could use properties to construct an open interval defined by a sequence with limit points of a larger closed interval. Then show the open union of these intervals approaches your closed one without explicitly talking about closure.

However any proof is going to have the idea of closure lurking somewhere in it since that's such an intricate part of this problem.